# SQL query to get 3 News with highest priority and if there is more than 3 ties, then according to startDate

Tags: mysql, subquery

i have the table news with columns:
id, title, brief, body, startDate, endDate, priority

and i need to select 3 news where the priority the highest and if there are more than 3 ties, select them according to the newest startDate
i've tried:

```
select * from (
    select *  from news order by priority DESC) as T  
order by startDate DESC limit 3;
```

but the problem is my SQL statement will first order the news by priority then pick up 3 of them according to start date but this is not right because it may take the 3 newest startDate news with priority less than max....

i could add limit 3 to the subquery but what if there are 5 news having max priority and took from them 3 only but the 4th or 5th has/have the newest startDate.

and if a made the subquery to return all records with max priority, may return only 2 news or 1 and i need 3.

Example to my problem, these records:

```
Title:first, startDate:today, priority: 5
Title:second , startDate:today, priority: 5 
Title:third , startDate:today, priority: 5
Title:fourth, startDate:today, priority: 5
Title:fifth, startDate:today, priority: 4
Title:sixth, startDate:tomorrow, priority: 4
```

i need to select first, second, and third.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by multiple columns without using a subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM news
ORDER BY priority DESC, startDate DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The second column is used when there's a tie in the first column.